# What is a different between laravel events and laravel functions?

Tags: laravel

please Give me some practical example when use laravel functions and laravel events
Any help is appriciated,
Thanks in advance by heart not just work but bottom by heart

Comment: What do you mean under *Laravel functions*?

Answer (score 1):

- A Function: is what something does.
- A Event: is something that happens.

Example:

```
openTheDoor(){
//this is function
}
```

But this function will execute when someone knock the door or door bell fires which is an event.

```
onDoorBell(){
 //This is an event
 openTheDoor();
}
```

Practical example

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{

    function checkUserIsActive(){
        //Consider this a function
    }
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //this is an event fires when user loggedin

        if(checkUserIsActive()){
            //This is function
            // Do something
        }
    }

}
```